# Operation cannot be performed in this event handler

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, datagridview

I'm trying to delete a row from a DataGridView
I use two types of instuctions
A

```
VouchersDGV.Rows.Clear()
```

B

```
If Not DGV.Rows(RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
                DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(RowIndex)
                DGV.Refresh()
            End If
```

Both of them from inside of

```
VouchersDGV_RowValidating
```

Event
 
I also run it from another Event Handler with RaiseEvent.
The last Event handler I'm useing it to escape from inside of the row in case of wrong typing or... what ever and bring the datagrid to it's initial position
The Event is

```
Private Sub Supplier_prod_EscapeOnFirstRowPressed() Handles Me.EscapeOnFirstRowPressed
```

To delete the row I'm enter to above EventHandler from

```
VouchersDGV_RowValidating
```

EventHandler and I take back the same error

```
DGV.Rows.RemoveAt(0) {"Operation cannot be performed in this event handler."}
```

Personally I can't understand why that happen and how i can give a solution
 
Is there anybody to know about this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point of validation, it is relying on a particular state, and it obviously isn't happy for you to start changing the rows when it only asked you to validate something. I can't say I blame it; having to re-validate the scenario after every event would get... confusing; better to prevent the change.

You could instead queue the item for removal, on a timer of another callback, or maybe there is a mechanism for saying "no" during validation.

Comment: @Marc What I'm trying to do is to delete the current row (after saving the data) and initialize the DataGridView.

Comment: @Lefteris simply: validation is not the time to do this

Comment: @Lefteris: if you're saving the data by doing something like clicking the Save button (?), it makes sense to delete the current row and re-initialize the DGV there (i.e. inside the Save button's click event).

Comment: @MusiGenesis I'm not using any button but I'm save the data after i leave the first row (that is what we need to do) after that I have to initialize the DataGridView

Comment: @Marc Yes I know that now and I'm trying to put it on another Event which take place after I leave the row ?!?!?

Comment: @Lefteris I wonder if a pragmatic option would be to use BeginInvoke to push an anon-method onto the message queue, I.e. `this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{grid.RemoveRow(whatever);});`

Comment: @Marc I haven't solve my issue yet. And Please is it posible to assist me on vb because I'm not familiar in c#

Comment: @Marc. I did a trick on my code. In the last Cell (No7) in the CellEnter event I'm Raise my own event EscapeOnFirstRowPressed which Normally is there to delete a row. When My Event Call comes to delete the row returns me the error of "Operation cannot be performed in this event handler.". BUT when I'm in the same Cell and pressing the ESC Key on my Keyboard My Event runs very good and the row is deleted. Can you understand what is this Phenomenon? Deleting the row from my keyboard and can't delete the row automatically?

Answer (score 4):

The `RowValidating` event is fired after a user has changed a row's contents and then attempts to move to another row.  The purpose of 'RowValidating' is to let you (the programmer) check the changes just made and cancel those changes and/or prevent the user from moving to a different row.  It makes sense, then, that you are prohibited from deleting the current row (or any other row) inside this event handler.

I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to accomplish here.  The `RowValidated` event (not `RowValidating`) may work for your purposes instead.

**Update:**  I think `RowLeave` is actually the event you want to use, and if not you can try a different event from this list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_events.aspx

Comment: I did what you told me (which defenetlly have sense) but returns the same error !?! I just want to delete the current row, and initialize the DataGridView

Comment: I know that place but wan't help me at all because this place is just a reference to the events and what I need is the exact position to remove a row. From the other hand i heve rebuilde it in a better structure and know I'm looking for the exact position to put on this Event(removerow)

Answer (score 2):

I have had the similar problem, my datagridview control was bound by dataBindingSource to BindingList of objects, and I was unable to remove a row from datagrid. The solution for me was remove an item from BindingList.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case I need to save changes when the user changes selection in DataGridView. I use `RowValidating` event to check any changes and ask the user to save them. But when I tried to save changes inside this handler I got exception `"Operation cannot be performed in this event handler."`

I was needed an event that rises after `RowValidating` and where I can save my changes. I didn't find such event. So I use timer for that. I start timer in `RowValidating` event and save my data when timer ticks.

Here is my code:

```
private void timerForSaving_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_saveChanges)
    {
        timerForSaving.Stop();
        SaveData();
        _saveChanges = false;
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_hasUnsavedChanges)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Question",
                                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            _saveChanges = true;
            timerForSaving.Start();
        }
    }
}
```