# Best way to remove a row from a DataGridView when it becomes blank

Tags: c#

I have a single-column DataGridView in my application.  What I would like is for the application to remove rows from the grid immediately if/when the user renders them blank (by editing the cell).  The problem is that I keep running into dead ends with every approach I try.

What is the best way to implement this behavior?  I have tried:

1. Using the **`CellValidated`** event and then checking whether the value is now blank.

   - Throws an "Operation cannot be performed" exception because, apparently, C# won't allow you to remove a row from a DataGridView in the `CellValidated` event.
2. Using the **`CellEndEdit`** event and then checking whether the value is now blank

   - Throws an "Operation cannot be performed" exception when I try to remove the row if the event that ended the cell edit was the user *clicked* another cell in the same grid; otherwise, this appears to work.
3. Using the **`CellValueChanged`** event and then checking whether the value is now blank.

   - Requires checking for whether the grid is currently being programmatically populated, but that's merely an inconvenience.
   - Misses the case where the user starts typing in a new row, then without validating, immediately deletes the text with BACKSPACE.  This leaves the cell empty and doesn't fire the `CellValueChanged` event.

I don't think that I can use the `CellLeave` event because the user can lock in a value without leaving a cell by hitting ENTER.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a bit late but here is how I did it

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
    {
        if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value == null)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot a couple of characters. )); Otherwise worked for me. BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
            }));

Answer (score 0):

I would use the CellStateChanged event.  Then, when a cell loses focus at some point (i.e. user selects some other cell) you can check it to see if it was left empty.  At that point, you can delete that row.  This will also be slightly faster, since you don't need to continuously check when a cell value is modified.  Otherwise, if you listen for cell value changes, the event-check will be firing all the time.

Comment: Nice try.  But this also causes an "Operation cannot be performed" exception.

Comment: hmm yeah these events are slightly limited. have you tried RowValidated? here is a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960232/operation-cannot-be-performed-in-this-event-handler

Comment: I hadn't, no.  I did just now, though, and it is also throwing the same type of exception.  That's too bad, I had a good feeling about that one.

Comment: Alright. Try it this way.  On the OnCellStateChanged event, set a flag like row_needs_deleted = row#.  Then, outside of the event, delete the row if row_needs_deleted > 0, and set it back to -1.

Comment: I had already thought of that.  But that won't work unless there is a place outside the event that we can use.  If the "place outside the event" is not another event, then I don't know how that would work.  Queueing up the deletion would probably cause a race condition.

Comment: ahh yeah this tricky. what if you checked the flag on a form click and keydown (tab/arrow) event?

Comment: This discussion is getting a bit long. Perhaps a separate answer post is in order.

P.S. If I'm going to have to use a flag, it makes more sense to set the flag in the CellValidated event.

Answer (score 0):

When form is created, set a flag, rowNumToDelete = -1.
OnCellValidated, if the cell is now empty, rowNumToDelete = row#.
OnKeyDown, if key is a (tab/arrow/enter) (or whatever keys a user can use to switch between cells in a grid), and if flag is > 0, delete the row at rowNumToDelete and set the flag back to -1.  Do the same for OnClick.  I'm still not sure if there is a better way to do it in a DataGridView event handler.